# IOS variable returning "null" when used in different method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have searched high and low and found many answers but none of them work.  It's probably something simple but it's eluding me.  Below are parts of my code.  I give the variable a value in the viewDidLoad method but it returns "null" when I try to use it in another method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

 NSString *returnedTN = TN;

JSONLoaderSched *jsonLoaderSched = [[JSONLoaderSched alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:scheduleA.json"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    teamSched = [jsonLoaderSched teamsFromJSONFile:url selectedTeam:returnedTN];

    subArray = [teamSched objectAtIndex:0];


});
}
```

---

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
NSLog(@"%@",teamSched);
NSLog(@"%@",subArray);

return [subArray count];
}
```

I've run NSLog with these variables from viewDidLoad and they print what they're supposed to.  But when I do the same from second method they both return "null".  I appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are doing a dangerous thing: you are *setting* the value of those instance variables on a background thread and *getting* them on the main thread.

And that is also the core of the problem. The problem is, because you are using a background thread to *set* them, you are getting them *before* the background thread has had a chance to set them, so of course they are still null.

The solution is: after you have set these variables back in `viewDidLoad` (and please, set them on the main thread!), now call `reloadData` (still on the main thread). That will cause the table methods to be called *again* and now you have data this time.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // get your data in the background
    id temp = [jsonLoaderSched teamsFromJSONFile:url selectedTeam:returnedTN];
    // now get back on the main thread!!!!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        teamSched = temp;
        subArray = [teamSched objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

Comment: Except there is a network access, which you shouldn't do on the main thread.

Comment: @Chuck Dude I said that

Answer (score 0):

The network access happens on a background thread. You need to reload the table view after it finishes, and for thread-safety you need to set the ivars and do the reload on the main thread.

Because UIViewControllers are thread-release-unsafe, you need to jump through the [weakSelf/strongSelf hoop](http://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/) to avoid rare but hard-to-debug crashes. (Otherwise, a -release could happen on a background thread, which means -dealloc could happen on the background thread, which does a lot of cleanup which isn't safe to do except on the main thread.)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSString *returnedTN = TN;

  JSONLoaderSched *jsonLoaderSched = [[JSONLoaderSched alloc] init];
  __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://adasoccerclub.org/scheduleA.json"];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    id sched = [jsonLoaderSched teamsFromJSONFile:url selectedTeam:returnedTN];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      __typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
      if (strongSelf) {
        strongSelf->teamSched = sched;
        strongSelf->subArray = [schedobjectAtIndex:0];
        [strongSelf.tableView reloadData];
      }
    };
  });
}
```

(I have no idea how Apple expects the average programmer to get this right.)

Comment: Weak-strong dance is to prevent retain cycle. No need for it here.

Comment: @matt That is not the only reason. A `UIViewController` is not safe to `-release` on a background thread, *referencing* it in a block is enough for it to be retained/released by the block, and passing the block to a background thread will likely cause it to be retained/released on the background thread.

Comment: @matt Concrete example: Imagine you unload the VC while the network request is outstanding. There is nothing retaining the VC except the "inner" block, nothing retaining the inner block except the "outer" block, and nothing retaining the outer block except the background thread/queue. The inner block briefly runs on the main thread, but there's a good chance that it will be released *first* on the main thread and *second* on the background thread, causing the VC's `-dealloc` to happen on the background thread, which is dangerous!